# Python Tkinter- GPIO Pin function not working

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am a beginner programmer so I have not got massive experience with Python. I have created a ultrasonic sensor system which logs water levels using the raspberry pi. My program works fine within the console, however I would like to make a GUI for it to make it more appealing using Tkinter. I have never used Tkinter before so I am unsure what I am doing wrong. I have made a button that should start the actual reading being taken, however every time I run I get an error telling me that I don't have access to GPIO and I should try running as root- although when I do this the same error appears.

Does anybody have any idea where I am going wrong or any alternative ways of it being run through a GUI? I'd appreciate any help as I have been stuck on this issue for over two months now, Many thanks!

The error message I am getting is this;

```
"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File 'user/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py', line 1426, in __call__
          return self.func(*args)
     File 'home.pi.tkinterproject.py', line 40 in run_code
          GPIO.setup(GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeErorr: No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!"
```

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)   

class Window(Frame):
def     __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master

        self.init_window()

def init_window(self):

        self.master.title("GUI")

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        quitButton = Button(self, text = "Quit", command = self.exit_window)
        quitButton.place(x = 330,y = 260)

        runButton = Button(self, text = "Run", command = self.run_code)
        runButton.place(x = 0, y = 0)


def exit_window(self):
        exit()

def run_code(self):
        #set pins according to BCM GPIO references
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        #set GPIO pins 
        TRIG = 23
        ECHO = 24            
        #sets trigger to send signal, echo to recieve the signal back
        GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)
        #sets output to low
        GPIO.output(TRIG,False)
        myLabell = Label(text = 'Initiating measurement').pack()
        print ("Initiating measurement..\n")
        #gives sensor time to settle for one second
        time.sleep(1)
        distance = averageReading()
        round(distance, 2)
        print ("Distance:", distance, "cm\n")
        print ("Saving your measurement to file..")
        ts = time.time()
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('     %H: %M: %S     %d-%m-%Y')
        textFile = open("sensorReadings" , "a")
        textFile.write(str(distance)+ "cm     recorded at: ")
        textFile.write(str(timestamp)+ "\n")
        textFile.close()           
        #resets pins for next time
        GPIO.cleanup()

global averageReading

def averageReading():
        readingOne = measure()
        time.sleep(0.1)         

        readingTwo = measure()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        readingThree = measure()
        reading = readingOne + readingTwo + readingThree
        reading = reading / 3
        return reading

global measure        

def measure():
        global measure
        #sends out the pulse to the trigger
        GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
        #short as possible
        time.sleep(0.00001)
        GPIO.output(TRIG,False)

        while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
                pulse_start = time.time()       
        while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
                pulse_end = time.time()
                pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start

                #half the speed of sound in cm/s
                distance = pulse_duration * 34300
                distance = distance / 2 
                #python function that rounds measurement to two digits
                round(distance, 2)
                return distance

myGUI = Tk()

myGUI.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(myGUI)

myGUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you include the exact error message you're getting?  I can see an error message on the RPi.GPIO wiki that looks like it might be what you describe here: http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/ but don't know if that's what you're actually seeing.

Comment: @ErikJohnson Hi there, the exact error message is this;

"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File 'user/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py', line 1426, in __call__
          return self.func(*args)
     File 'home.pi.tkinterproject.py', line 40 in run_code
          GPIO.setup(GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeErorr: No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!"

Comment: You said you get the same error when running as `root`.  Can you show us the exact command line you're using to run your code as the `root` user?

Comment: Hi @larsks, Stack overflow are not allowing me to upload a picture- I enter on the command line 'sudo python tkinterproject.py' and get the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "tkinterproject.py", line 9 in <module>
            class Window(Frame):
      File "tkinterproject.py", line 58 in Window
             distance = averageReading()
NameError: global name 'averageReading' is not defined

Comment: *Never* upload pictures of text.  Just update your question with the actual text, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Note that you are NOT getting the same error when running as root. Had you posted the other error earlier, the problem would have been much easier to answer. Your error messages will give you a lot of information, read them carefully.  @larsks has given you a correct answer for your first set of issues; good luck on solving the next set.

Answer (score 1):

The first error:

```
RuntimeErorr: No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!"
```

Means exactly what it says: you need to run your code as `root` in order to have appropriate access to the GPIO subsystem.  When running as `root`, you get a different error:

```
NameError: global name 'averageReading' is not defined
```

This is happening due to errors in your code.  First, you appear to have both a global variable *and* a function with the same name.  Remove this line:

```
global averageReading
```

And also:

```
global measure
```

The `global` statement is for creating global *variables*, and only makes sense when used inside a function block.

There are a number of formatting problems in the code you've posted (there is missing indentation at on several lines), and it's hard to tell if this is just a copy/paste problem or if your code is actually incorrect.

Please try to fix any formatting issues in your question so that it matches your actual code.

Also, `ECHO` and `TRIG` are used in the `measure` function but aren't visible from there, so you'll need to fix this.

Comment: Thank you @larsks, when I run as root I get the error: "global name 'averageReading' is not defined", is this something to do with the method not being able to be accessed? Is there a way I could make the method 'global'?

Comment: There are still substantial indentation errors in the code you have posted.  Until you fix your question so that it is syntactically correct, it is hard to diagnose any other errors you may encounter.

Comment: I do not have any indentation errors in my code, it was the way it was pasted. @larsks

Comment: And as I have requested multiple times, you need to fix your question so that the code there is accurate.  Otherwise, it is impossible for us to tell whether or not your problems are due to basic formatting problems in your code. We should be able to copy and paste your code to reproduce the error you are seeing.